# Programatically configure Office 2010 Word Ribbon via VBA

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, office-2007, office-2010

Is it possible to configure a Ribbon (e.g. adding a tab etc.) in Office 2010 programatically via VBA? I.e. by writing VBScript code in a macro.

Br. Morten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can manipulate* a Ribbon tab and its controls using VBA, but you *cannot create* one. Not with the Object Model anyway. The best you could do - somehow - is to get some kind of OPC dll (like an ActiveX component) that handles opening/relationships/closing of OPC documents (like .docx documents) and old school MSXML for creating a ribbon definition and adding it to the package.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog post for Excel

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=265636

and this one for Word

http://www.wordarticles.com/Shorts/RibbonVBA/RibbonVBADemo.htm

Comment: Hi, it seems to me that neither of these are solving the problem of adding new tabs (in general, adding Ribbon XML) using pure VBA? I was hoping for something like:

Dim customUiXml As String
customXml = "<mso:customUI yada yada"
Smth.RunMyXml(customUiXml)

Answer (score 1):

If your UI is static, i.e. you don't need to programatically change the behavior of, or add/remove UI elements on the fly, you can define a customUI within a macro-enabled template. You can use your VBA functions as call-backs for the UI elements defined in the XML.

Have a look at [this guide](http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm). In a nutshell, you define a `customUI\customUI14.xml` file within the .dotm archive. This XML describes your custom ribbon elements using [this schema](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C2AA691A-8004-46AC-9852-102F1D5BCD18&displaylang=en).

This definitely works for Word templates (.dotm files). I think a similar approach works for any OOXML format.

Comment: This is the answer